# NOW() in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, datetime

I am just wondering if there is an easy way to make the function "now()", in Excel, just to work when a modification is done on the workbook, and not when the workbook is opened.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/954-excel-created-last-modified-time.html#three

and try using the second macro from:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Range("A2").Value = Format(ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time"), "short date")
End Sub
```

Replace A2 with the cell you want to put that last modified time in.

you can also add:

```
Public Function ModDate()
ModDate = Format(FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName), "m/d/yy h:n ampm")
End Function
```

and then call:

```
=ModDate()
```

EDIT:

You can also use:
FileDateTime()

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/filedatetime.php

You'd have to figure out how to get the file to refer to itself.

Bear in mind though, that a file is changed by being opened, so it might as well be the current time. For more on this, see:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826741

So NOW() might be all you have. Also, you can search Excel's components in program files, but if NOW is written in its binary, it might not be changeable.

However...

According to microsoft,

> Making your custom functions available anywhere
>
> To use a custom function, the workbook containing the module in which
>   you create the function must be open. If that workbook is not open,
>   you get a #NAME? error when you try to use the function. Even if the
>   workbook is open, if you use the function in a different workbook, you
>   must precede the function name with the name of the workbook in which
>   the function resides. For example, if you create a function called
>   Discount in a workbook called Personal.xls, and you call that function
>   from another workbook, you must write =personal.xls!Discount(), not
>   simply =Discount().
>
> You can save yourself some keystrokes (and possible typing errors) by
>   selecting your custom functions from the Insert Function dialog box.
>   (Your custom functions appear in the User Defined category.) An easier
>   way to make your custom functions available at all times is to store
>   them in a separate workbook and then save that workbook as an add-in
>   (an XLA file) in your XLStart folder. (The XLStart folder is a
>   subfolder of the folder containing your Excel files. When you start
>   Excel, the program opens any documents it finds in XLStart.) To save a
>   workbook as an add-in, choose File, Save As (or File, Save). Then
>   choose Microsoft Excel Add-in from the Files Of Type list.
>
> If your user-defined functions are stored in an XLA file that is
>   present in memory, you don't have to specify the name of that file
>   when you call a function. If the XLA file is saved in your XLStart
>   folder, it will be present in memory whenever you run Excel.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/creating-custom-functions-HA001111701.aspx

So it seems implied that, provided user defined functions are in that workbook, they should work just fine wherever the file is.

Hope that gives you your answer.

Comment: I understand what you did, but there is a way that I can do this without a macro. The reason is because what it is going happen if the user has the macro disable?